# Already have a gradient on my UIView, having trouble inserting a new one

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, gradient

This is the code I already have:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = backGradient.frame;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[newGradientTop CGColor], (id)[newGradientBottom CGColor], nil];
[backGradient.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

I'm now trying to show a new gradient instead, using the same block of code but different colours going into it. But the new gradient doesn't show, and i think this is because it will not show above the already existing gradient.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Use this function (replacing old gradient layer with the new one):

```
#define kGradientLayerKey @"MyGradientLayer"

void makeViewGradient(UIView *pView,CGColorRef clr1,CGColorRef clr2)
{
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    [gradient setValue:@"1" forKey:kGradientLayerKey];

    gradient.frame = pView.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)clr1,(id)clr2,nil];

    CALayer *pGradientLayer = nil;
    NSArray *ar = pView.layer.sublayers;
    for (CALayer *pLayer in ar)
    {
        if ([pLayer valueForKey:kGradientLayerKey])
        {
            pGradientLayer = pLayer;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!pGradientLayer) [pView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    else [pView.layer replaceSublayer:pGradientLayer with:gradient];

    pView.backgroundColor = nil;//free memory !
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding additional layers, keep track of your original layer and replace it with your new one. You probably mean to use `-replaceSublayer:with:` here.

Answer (score 0):

`[backGradient.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0]` inserts the new layer at the bottom of the stack, under any other layers. Try 
`[backGradient.layer addSublayer:gradient]` instead.